# install zend sketelon for very very newbie

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, zend-framework

i have been installed  wamp, google chrome, postgre sql, mysql.
i have problem with istalling zend framework, curl, sketelon application.
i search tutorial from youtube, google, developt of zend, but i cant follow them because some of the step is missing and i want to know how to do that and where i start to learn to become web program, my purpose is to make blog with zend.

so if you have full tutorial please give me the link or share here, 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the "Zend Skeleton Application" from https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication
2. Unzip the same
3. Basic Skeleton Application setup - open command prompt, and run command 
   A. "php ./composer.phar self-update"
   a. it will update the composer - dependency manager
   B. "php ./composer.phar update"

   C. "php ./composer.phar install"

   Note:-if there is occurs following problem in this step
       [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https]
       then you should enable openssl by removing semicolon(;)                         Find line ;extension=php_openssl.dll in D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini and       uncomment it (by removing ;).
   a. it will install zend framework and other dependencies. 
   b. zend framework will be installed at ./vendor/zendframework

vHost Setup

One time setup
1. Create a new vhost to allow direct access to the development area using the guide http://cesaric.com/?p=255
2. Create a document root for zend base-directory in httpd.conf file similar to lines of     DocumentRoot "d:/wamp/www/" [change path]

```
Note-if there is an error check your xxx-error.log file, 

find file in following path

D:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\logs\xxx-error.log

if it has following line

D:/zend/zend_test/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or      defined by a module not included in the server configuration

then go to wampserver->apache->apache modules and check rewrite_module and then restart your        wampserver and check your site
```

Every project setup
1. edit hosts file from "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"
2. Create a virtualhost in file httpd-vhosts.conf in apache folder

For each module
1. Download the "Zend Skeleton Module" from https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule and start building the same

For more details refer below link http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Comment: in command from where i shloud type "php./composer.phar self-update", because -> 'php.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Refer the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

Comment: setting the environtment variables is the missing step. :) so i can use php in the cmd

Comment: can you help me now, i want to install zend skeleton application in my PC but i want to use php.5.4 because some apps in my pc doesnt work on php 5.5

Answer (score 1):

There is a getting started guide provide by the zend [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/overview.html)
And generating for a blog I personally found **mwop.net** it's owner name **Matthew Weier O'Phinney** . He is a lead person of zend framework at  zend technology and his blog mwop.net is really a great example ever I found on the internet and by many people. He is also talking about why and how made his blog [here](https://mwop.net/blog/2012-05-developing-a-zf2-blog.html) .

You can find his blog source code [here](https://github.com/weierophinney/mwop.net/) and it's having latest code of zend framework so once you follow his blog than you probably find the best zend framework coding standard with coding pattern ever.

This is a start up with the zend framework. follow the leader you find the best things ever.

[Github](https://github.com/vrkansagara) 
 [Twitter](https://twitter.com/vrkansagara)

you can also follow this artical for how To install the zf2 skeleton [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562617/installing-zend-framework-2-on-xampp-in-windows?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, but i stuck in make progress, i will learn from the very very begining,   like introduction, place the folder and more more. i going error even in  make hello world application. zend is amazing, I WANT LEARN ZEND..

Comment: it's cool for you but i dont understand that why dont give credit for giving an answer.