# Laravel artisan wamp CLI

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

So I have a terminal and i am currently sitting in my project root where laravel and artisan sit.  I am unable to call php or php artisan in the terminal...  I can't do migrations or anything else and not sure what I am missing.

'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add folder with `php.exe` to your system PATH variable:

- Go to Control Panel and open the System icon (Start → Control Panel)
- Go to the Advanced tab
- Click on the 'Environment Variables' button
- Look into the 'System Variables' pane
- Find the Path entry (you may need to scroll to find it)
- Double click on the Path entry
- Enter your PHP directory at the end, including ';' before (e.g.
  ;C:\php)
- Press OK

Restart your computer to make `php artisan` commands work.

Comment: This works thanks!  Any idea how to make artisan work with wamp mysql?  After trying to run a migration I get: [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1130] Host 'cpe-184-56-126-15.neo.res.rr.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server.  I am guessing I need to change the credentials in my .env file but not sure where to find those in WAMP

Comment: I figured it.  Thanks!