# Setting up PHPUnit on Windows Machine getting error running 'phpunit --version' php not recognised

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

Hi I'm following the instructions on this site for installing PHPUnit on Windows. https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html

I've followed the instructions exactly but when I attempt to run step 6

```
`C:\Users\username> phpunit --version
```

I get the error:

> 'php is not recognized as an internal or external command'.

From what I've read online it seems to be a path problem. My path is set to C:\bin as in the instructions and my phpunit.cmd and phpunit.phar are both in there. Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what to do next can anyone help?

Edit: Don't think this question is a duplicate, I had a PHP system variable path set up before with no problem, plus the problem is php is not recognised, not php.exe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [‘php.exe’ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: Still stuck with this problem can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have php.exe in "C:\bin"?

Comment: The linked question should solve your problem. If the directory with "php.exe" is in your path, phpunit.cmd will be able to execute "php".