# Run laravel project files on wamp server without laravel and composer install

Tags: laravel, file, directory, wamp

I'm currently new in laravel, I have laravel project files and I paste it to my www folder. I would like to ask if it is possible or is there any way to run a laravel project without installing composer and laravel in my localhost wamp server?

Comment: you should use composer, its better to use composer., if your project already have composer installed you can run it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run laravel project on windows without composer just follow the instruction :

1. Goto your project folder
2. Press Shift + Right Button
3. Select "open command window here" menu
4. It will open a command line then write "php artisan serve" command
5. It will active internal server in laravel and you will get an url looks like  http://localhost:8000
6. So in the address bar of web browser put http://localhost:8000 and hit enter. Hope you will access your project.

**But for the development purpose you have to install composer.**

hope it will helpful. Let me know if you get any problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a problem it says 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: php artisan serve didn;t recognized.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291317/php-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-command-prompt/31291382

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464315/php-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/16c0ux1.jpg Thanks I have already run the program but when I try to run the http://localhost:8000/ it gives me error. It says: 
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'server.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: your provided image link does not open. Anyways, you should not run localhost:8000 at command line. You have to put this url to browser address bar and press enter

Comment: Sorry, I mean I run it on my browser Sir. That's the page said

Comment: can you please share the screenshot after run "php artisan serve" ?

Comment: Sorry to here that, I used tinypic.com but now I'm using imgurl. Here's the image: http://i.imgur.com/HPC9MlU.jpg. And Here's the image of error page: http://imgur.com/4X1Bkul

Comment: oh very good. I saw your image. I found that your larval server has been started. Now goto web browser and put `http://localhost:8000` to address bar then you'll get your application. once you get any error in the browser just share another screenshot as an image again.

Comment: i think you have problem in your application. There is need to update composer file. So i know you don't have composer. Try another way, goto localhost -> click on your project -> it will show all folder in your laravel project then click on "public" folder. then see the happens

Comment: can you give me your TeamViewer access so that i can see what's happening

Comment: Thank you Sir for helping me out, I found out that I have bugs to fix first before I can see the output. I mean my project files has lot to work on and I should post another new topic for this.